# What is the preferred way to set up personal finances?

Tags: credit, checking-account, savings-account, financial-advisor

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a personal finance system that is simple. I want to know things like: How many bank accounts should I have and what kinds, and how much (percentage-wise) of my income should I put into each one? Then from there, how do I portion them out into budgets and savings? Should I use credit cards for spending to reap benefits?

I'm basically looking for a simple system that'll organize and structure the way money flows in and out of my bank accounts.

Even if you could recommend good books, best practices, web articles, et cetera that would be great. I'm just looking for some direction.

Thanks,
ejay

Answer (score 1):

The absolute best advice I ever received was this:

You will need three categories of savings in your life:

1) Retirement Savings 
This is money you put away (in 401-Ks and IRAs) for the time in your life when you can no longer earn enough income to support yourself. You do *not* borrow against it nor do you withdraw from it in emergencies or to buy a house.

2) Catestrophic savings 
This is money you put back in case of serious events. Events like: prolonged job loss, hospitalization, extended illness, loss of home, severe and significant loss of transportation, very large aplliance loss or damage. You do not take trips to the Bahamas or buy diamond rings with this money.

3) Urgent, relatively small,  need savings. This is the savings you can use from time to time. Use it for bills that arise unexpectedly, unforseen shortfalls in your budget, needed repairs such as car repairs and small appliance repairs, surprising fines, fees, and bills.

Put 10% of your income into each category of savings. 10% intro retirement savings, another, separate, 10% intro Catestrophic savings, and yet another 10% intro urgent, small need, savings.

So, as you can see, already 30% of your income is already spoken for. Divide up the remaining 70% intro fixed (I recommend 50% toward fixed expenses) and variable expenses. Fixed includes those things that you pay once every month such as housing, utilities, car payment, debt repayment, etc. Variable includes discretionary things like eating out, gifts, and  splurges.

Most importantly, partner with someone who is your opposite. If you are a saver at heart partner with a spender. If you are a spender partner with a saver.

There are three rules to live by regarding the budget: A) no one spends any money unless it is in the budget B) the budget only includes those things to which both the saver and the spender agree C) the budget can, and will, be modified as the pay period unfolds.

A budget is a plan not a means to beat the other person up. Plans change as new information arises. A budget must be flexible. The urgent use savings will help to make  the budget flexible.

Edit due to comments:
@enderland Perhaps you do not have children living with you. I am a saver, my wife is a spender. When it came time to do the budget I would forget things like the birthdays of my children, school fees due next pay period, shopping for Christmas gifts, needed new clothes and shoes for the children, broken small appliances that needed to be fixed or replaced, special (non reoccurring) house maintenence (like steam cleaning the carpet), gifts to relatives and friends, exceptional assistance to relatives, etc.  As my wife was the spender she would remind me of these things.

Perhaps  you do not have these events in your life. I am glad to have these events in my life as that means that I have people in my life that I care about.

What good is a fat savings account if I have no loved ones that benefit from it?

Comment: while the question doesn't reference a partner, I've found the concept of "my money, your money, our shared expenses" useful. Specifically, during the inevitable trying times in a relationship, if your non-working partner/spouse has her own money (and hence live alone), it's MUCH easier to stay... former investment advisor

Comment: `Most importantly, partner with someone who is your opposite. If you are a saver at heart partner with a spender. If you are a spender partner with a saver.` <--- this is a horrible idea. I don't understand what makes you say this.  It might make sense for spenders, because a saver gives stability and help you have financial security. For savers, though, most of us are comfortable and ok with how much we spend and we don't feel deprived. The idea that we _need_ to spend more to be happy is annoying and not helpful at all (in extreme cases might be true, but most savers I know aren't miserly).

Comment: @enderland he meant by *spender* who spends big for him/her by him/her? or pay a big portion of the money they both owes? Kinda related: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/57391/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-set-up-personal-finances#comment90120_57396

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of personal preference and personal circumstance that goes into these decisions.  I think that for a person starting out, what's below is a good system.  People with greater needs probably aren't reading this question looking for an answer.

> How many bank accounts should I have and what kinds, and how much (percentage-wise) of my income should I put into each one?

You should probably have one checking account and one savings / money market account.  If you're total savings are too low to avoid fees on two accounts, then just the checking account at the beginning.  Keep the checking account balance high enough to cover your actual debits plus a little buffer.  Put the rest in savings.

Multiple bank accounts beyond the basics or using multiple banks can be appropriate for some people in some circumstances.  Those people, for the most part, will have a specific reason for needing them and maybe enough experience at that point to know how many and where to get them. (Else they ask specific questions in the context of their situation.)

I did see a comment about partners - If you're married / in long-term relationship, you might replicate the above for each side of the marriage / partnership.  That's a personal decision between you and your partner that's more about your philosophy in the relationship then about finance specifically.

> Then from there, how do I portion them out into budgets and savings?

I personally don't believe that there is any generic answer for this question.  Others may post answers with their own rules of thumb.  You need to budget based on a realistic assessment of your own income and necessary costs.  Then if you have money some savings.  Include a minimal level of entertainment in "necessary costs" because most people cannot work constantly.  Beyond that minimal level, additional entertainment comes after necessary costs and basic savings.  Savings should be tied to your long term goals in addition to you current constraints.

> Should I use credit cards for spending to reap benefits?

No. Use credit cards for the convenience of them, if you want, but pay the full balance each month and don't overdo it.  If you lack discipline on your spending, then you might consider avoiding credit cards completely.

Answer (score 1):

simplicity and roi are often at odds. the simplest plan that also supports a reasonable investment return would have 3 accounts:

1. checking account. your checking account receives your paychecks and is used for everyday spending. a good checking account will be free and can return fairly decent interest rate. look for a local bank or credit union that offers a "kasasa" style account. those accounts have some fine print (like minimum debit card transactions per month), but are generally a good deal.
2. brokerage account. the brokerage account is your emergency fund and large expense savings. it should receive regularly scheduled transfers from your checking account (e.g. 10% of your pre-tax income). this money can be used for large expenses like replacing a furnace or a down payment on a house. once you have a few months savings, try not to go below that mark when paying an elective expense (e.g. a new car). robinhood.com is a new brokerage company that offers no-frills trading for free. no commissions and no monthly or annual fees. even without fees, you might limit your stock purchases to only once every few months just to keep your taxes simple.  also, limit stock sales to only when you need the cash. just be sure to keep track of when you bought and sold (and at what price). simply buying an s&p500 index fund is a simple and (relatively) safe move.
3. retirement account (e.g. ira or 401k). this account should also receive regularly scheduled transfers from your checking account or directly from your employer (e.g. 10% of your pre-tax income). check the contribution limits for the current tax year against your income to make sure you don't go over (especially with the ira). tradeking is a good option for an ira account, they offer ira's with low commissions and no annual or monthly fees.

if you want to get better returns on your investments, things can get much more complicated. here are some optional accounts to consider:

1. various credit cards offer cash back on your regular spending.  the highest rate of return is usually on sign-up bonuses, these bonuses can pay over 300$ every 3 months, but can require you to spend large amounts of money (e.g. 3k$). the second highest return comes in the cards that offer 5% back on certain categories, but that requires you to use different cards for different categories and may have low spending limits (e.g. 250$/mo).  the simplest cards are citi double cash, or discover which both currently offer (effectively) 2% back on everything.  for discover, the offer is only for the first year, and not everyone takes discover, but they also offer 5% categories by quarter. you should **absolutely not** consider getting a credit card unless you are totally confident you will always pay off the full balance every month. in addition to credit cards, some banks offer sign-up bonuses for checking accounts, just be sure to check the fine print for how long the account must remain open or other gotchas. if you really want to push the envelope, you can use 0% interest offers as a source of cash for leveraged investments.
2. over your lifetime, you will probably accumulate multiple ira and 401k accounts. the strategies of combining and rolling over those accounts is a large topic with many dedicated posts. just keep in mind that the savvy investor can withdraw money long before retirement, or contribute well over the normal limits (if using the right strategy). on the other hand, a savvy investor can usually get larger tax breaks from a regular brokerage account than an ira, if they carefully manage the timing of when they realize gains and losses. this is true at least for the first 3k$ in capital losses per year (~50k$+ of savings). unfortunately, the more profitable strategies tend to involve more regular attention and paperwork.
3. home ownership can be a leveraged investment that comes with large tax breaks. however, it can also keep you from accepting employment further away, and you might accidentally buy more house than you need. on the other hand, it does sort of force you to save, if you do not have the discipline to invest on your own.
4. debt management is a topic all on it's own. if you have debt (especially credit card debt), you might look at dave ramsey's "total money makeover". it has a step-by-step format, i think you might appreciate.

besides the mechanics of money flowing between accounts, a budget helps you understand and control your spending.  while there are many methods for this (e.g. envelopes of cash, separate accounts for various types of expenses), the simplest might be using mint.com.  just be sure to put all your spending on a credit or debit card, and you can see your spending by category when you log into mint. it can take a bit to get it set up, and your bank needs to be compatible, but it can give you a really good picture of where your money is going.  once you know that, you can start making decisions like "i should spend less on coffee", or "i should go to the zoo more", based on how much things cost vs how much you enjoy them. if you feel like your spending is out of control, then you can set yourself hard limits on certain kinds of spending, but usually just watching and influencing your own choices is enough.

notes:

if you have a spouse or partner, you should each maintain your own separate accounts. there are many reasons for this including simplicity and roi, besides the obvious. if you feel you must have a joint account, be sure to clearly define how it should be used (e.g. only for paying the utilities) and funded (x$ per month each). particularly with your house, do not do joint ownership. one of you should be a renter and the other a landlord.

some of these statements assume you are in the usa.

on a personal note, i have about 20 credit cards, 2 checking accounts, 2 ira's, 2 brokerage accounts, and 3 401k's. but i consider myself a personal finance hobbyist, and spend an absurd amount of time chasing financial deals and tax breaks.

Comment: why do you recommend putting your emergency fund in a brokerage account? Putting it in a savings account seems more typical and safer

Comment: @pushkin simplicity mostly. that said a brokerage account is nearly as safe as a savings account if you only invest in a money market fund (e.g. jpst).  you have to keep in mind that even high yield savings accounts were paying less than 1% interest back in 2015. plus using a brokerage account lets you invest in equities using the same account once you have enough "emergency" money to take some risk. even if you decided to go 100% stocks on day one it's highly unlikely that the stock market will crash before you are well past the "emergency" post.

Answer (score 1):

You don't state where you are, so any answers to this will by necessity be very general in nature.

> How many bank accounts should I have and what kinds

You *should have* one transaction account and one savings account. You *can get by* with just a single transaction account, but I really don't recommend that.

These are referred to with different names in different jurisdictions, but the basic idea is that you have one account where money is going in and out (the transaction account), and one where money goes in and stays (the savings account).

You can then later on, *as you discover various needs,* build on top of that basic foundation. For example, I have separate accounts for each source of money that comes into my personal finances, which makes things much easier when I sit down to fill out the tax forms up to almost a year and a half later, but also adds a bit of complexity. For me, that simplicity at tax time is worth the additional complexity; for someone just starting out, it might not be. (And of course, it is *completely* unnecessary if you have only one source of taxable income and no other specific reason to separate income streams.)

> how much (percentage-wise) of my income should I put into each one?

With a single transaction account, your entire income will be going into that account. Having a single account to pay money into will also make life easier for your employer.

You will then have to work out a budget that says how much you plan to spend on food, shelter, savings, and so on.

> how do I portion them out into budgets and savings?

If you have no idea where to start, but have an appropriate financial history (as opposed to just now moving into a household of your own), bring out some old account statements and categorize each line item in a way that makes sense to you. Don't be too specific; four or five categories will probably be plenty. These are categories like "living expenses" (rent, electricity, utilities, ...), "food and eating out" (everything you put in your mouth), "savings" (don't forget to subtract what you take *out* of savings), and so on. This will be your initial budget.

If you have no financial history, you are probably quite young and just moving out from living with your parents. Ask them how much might be reasonable in your area to spend on basic food, a place to live, and so on. Use those numbers as a starting point for a budget of your own, but don't take them as absolute truths.

Always have a "miscellaneous expenses" or "other" line in your budget. There will *always* be expenses that you didn't plan for, and/or which don't neatly fall into any other category. Allocate a *reasonable* sum of money to this category. This should be where you take money from during a normal month when you overshoot in some budget category; your savings should be a *last* resort, *not* something you tap into on a regular basis. (If you find yourself needing to tap into your savings on a regular basis, adjust your budget accordingly.)

Figure out based on your projected expenses and income how much you can reasonably set aside and not touch. It's impossible for us to say exactly how much this will be. Some people have trouble setting aside 5% of their income on a regular basis without touching it; others easily manage to save over 50% of their income. *Don't worry if this turns out a small amount at first.* Get in touch with your bank and set up an automatic transfer from your transaction account to the savings account, set to recur each and every time you get paid (you may want to allow a day or two of margin to ensure that the money has arrived in your account before it gets taken out), of the amount you determined that you can save on a regular basis. Then, try to forget that this money ever makes it into your finances. This is often referred to as the "pay yourself first" principle.

You won't hit your budget exactly every month. Nobody does. In fact, it's more likely that *no* month will have you hit the budget exactly. Try to stay under your budgeted expenses, and when you get your next pay, unless you have a large bill coming up soon, transfer whatever remains into your savings account.

Spend some time at the end of each month looking back at how well you managed to match your budget, and make any necessary adjustments. If you do this regularly, it won't take very long, and it will *greatly* increase the value of the budget you have made.

> Should I use credit cards for spending to reap benefits?

*Only* if you would have made those purchases anyway, *and* have the money on hand to pay the bill *in full* when it comes due. Using credit cards to pay for things is a great convenience in many cases. **Using credit cards to pay for things that you couldn't pay for using cash instead, is a recipe for financial disaster.**

---

People have also mentioned investment accounts, brokerage accounts, etc. This is good to have in mind, but in my opinion, the exact "savings vehicle" (type of place where you put the money) is a lot less important than *getting into the habit of saving regularly and not touching that money.* That is why I recommend just a savings account: if you miscalculate, forgot a large bill coming up, or for any other (good!) reason need access to the money, it won't be at a time when the investment has dropped 15% in value and you face a large penalty for withdrawing from your retirement savings.

*Once you have a good understanding of how much you are able to save reliably, you can divert a portion of that into other savings vehicles, including retirement savings.* In fact, at that point, you probably should.

Also, I suggest making a list of every single bill you pay regularly, its amount, when you paid it last time, and when you expect the next one to be due. Some bills are easy to predict ("$234 rent is due the 1st of every month"), and some are more difficult ("the electricity bill is due on the 15th of the month after I use the electricity, but the amount due varies greatly from month to month"). This isn't to know exactly how much you will have to pay, but to ensure that you aren't surprised by a bill that you didn't expect.